# Returning a True or False from an IIF statement

Tags: ms-access

I have a query with the following IIF statement

**OnlineEnrolment: IIf([qry_ebs_final_CAN-ENROL-ONLINE].[SP_CAN_ENROL]='Y',True,False)**

It gives the correct results, but the format that it gives them is what I am struggling with.  It responds back with 0 or -1.   I want it to respond TRUE or FALSE.

How can I change this other than making TRUE and FALSE strings?  I still want them as boolean values.

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: 0 and -1 are how Access represents boolean values. What's wrong with that? If this is for display purposes, then you'll need to convert the values to strings anyway to make the UI independent of the database representation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how TRUE and FALSE work in VBA (and Access): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275800/what-are-the-integer-values-of-boolean-false-and-true-in-vb6

If you want a 1 and a 0 like most other programming languages, return 1 and 0 and evaluate that instead of using the keywords TRUE and FALSE. That will make it consistent with other languages, but it won't be internally consistent with Access/VBA.

Something like this:

```
    IIf([qry_ebs_final_CAN-ENROL-ONLINE].[SP_CAN_ENROL]='Y',1,0)
```

Comment: so the whole workflow where this fits in is. There is a table which has a number of fields which are Data Type Yes/No and format True/False so that in the form they appear as tick boxes.  Then the query that includes the above IIF statement outputs in conjunction  with the table into an excel spreadsheet.  Depending on whether the true/false comes from the field or the query, it displays either right aligned or left..

Comment: In Excel, what do the results look like in terms of their differences? An example might help illustrate the problem.

Comment: They are the same, just the ones which come from a table are right aligned and the ones which come from the IIF query are left aligned.